# Weird javascript number behavior

Tags: javascript, function, numbers

If you run this code you get 599052. It does this for any number this length until it contains an 8 or 9 generally. Also if the starting number is not a 0 it will work. This really stumped me and I scoured the web to no avail. I'm hoping someone here has some insight into what is going on here.

```
var addd = function (num) {
  return num;
};

addd(02222014);
```

Comment: That's because numbers with a leading zero in JavaScript are considered octal.

Comment: add "use strict" at the top to fix it.

Comment: @dandavis Then it will throw `SyntaxError: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated`. Integers can't begin with a leading zero, but implementations may (in non-strict mode) parse them as LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral.

Comment: Octal numbers are 0-7, which have 3 bits. having an 8 or 9 in there makes the number NOT octal, since 8 and 9 take 4 bits each. That would explain why without the 8 or 9 and with the leading zero you get "weird" numbers, but without the leading zero or with an 8 or 9 you get "normal" numbers.

Comment: Thanks @j08691 
So is there a way to revert base 8 in the function or is this one of those never allow an integer to start with zero moments? I'm working with dates so naturally some months/days need a zero in front and I can't neccissarily do math with strings.